# Why are there so many universal properties in math?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, field-theory

I don't really understand why there are so many universal properties in math or why they all need to be highlighted.

For example, I'm studying some Algebra right now.  I have found three universal properties that are all basically saying the same thing, although the details are different:

> **Universal property 1**: If $R, S$ are rings and $\theta: R \to S$ is a ring map, then for each $s \in S$, there is a unique map $\hat{\theta_{s}} : R[x] \to S$ such that if $i: R \to R[x]$ is the inclusion map, we get $\theta = \hat{\theta_{s}} \circ i$.
>
> **Universal property 2**: If $D$ is an integral domain and $F$ is a field with $\phi : D \to F$ a one-to-one ring map, then there is a unique map $\hat{\phi} : Q(D) \to F$ such that $\hat{\phi} \circ \pi = \phi$, where $\pi : D \to Q(D)$ sends $a$ to $\frac{a}{1}$ ($Q(D)$ the fractional field of $D$).

*Universal property two* was used to prove that in a field of characteristic $0$, the rationals are a subfield, and in a field of characteristic $p$ ($p$ prime), $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a subfield.

> **Universal property 3**: If $R, S$ are rings, $\phi: R \to S$ is a ring map, and $I$ is an ideal such that $I \subseteq \text{ker}(\phi)$, then there is a unique map $\overline{\phi} : R/I \to S$ such that $\phi = \overline{\phi} \circ i$ where $i: R \to R/I$ maps $a$ to $\overline{a}$.

It is really hard for me to keep track of all of these universal properties, especially when they are all usually referenced by the single name "universal property".  Is there a point to all of these universal properties?

Honestly, I don't even know if my question is clear, or how to ask a better question in this regard.

Comment: Its a universal property of category theory. Sometimes the truth is bland.

Comment: Maybe you want category theory for a broader, unifying view? Or do I mistake your question?

Comment: I second this question, I'm also being introduced to universal properties but without the context of category theory and it is very confusing/hard to grasp what a universal property even is.

Comment: What you refer to as Universal Property 1, 2 and 3 is usually referred to as Universal property of polynomial rings, universal property of fraction fields, universal property of quotients respectively. It will be difficult for you to remember these universal properties if you just label them as universal properties 1, 2 and 3. The motivation for this comes from category theory.

Comment: @Rankeya I have a mathematically inclined friend that says he doesn't understand, for example, cosets of the quotient ring $R/I$, for a ring $R$ and ideal $I \subseteq R$, and instead understands the quotient ring in terms of the universal property for quotients.  I have absolutely no idea how to interpret, or peek into, his perspective.  How can the universal property give any intuition for $R/I$ without thinking about cosets?

Comment: Many objects in mathematics are universal, in the sense that they are initial/terminal objects in a suitably constructed category. I recommend reading about the Yoneda Lemma and Representable functors to get a better sense of universal properties. All the objects you mentioned in your question above represent some very particular functor. For example $R/I$ represents the functor that associates to each ring $R$ the collection of ring homomorphisms $R \rightarrow S$ which maps all of $I$ to $0$.

Comment: So the answer is: "Because there are so many functors".

Comment: @user46944: I wouldn't worry about universal properties too much if this is your first time studying abstract algebra. I thought of $R/I$ as a collection of cosets when I first learned about rings. But with time, as I read more, universal properties and constructions made sense.

Comment: @Rankeya It just bothers me because when I am learning something, and I need to prove later statements, if I invoke the earlier proven statements in my later proofs, I always mentally run through the proof of the statement I want to use.  But each of these universal properties requires different proofs, so it is hard to keep track of the proofs in my mind when I am proving later statements.  Thanks for your input and help.

Comment: @user46944: I am very sure you will get used to it with time and more familiarity. At least that happened with me! Good luck.

Comment: @user46944 Universal properties are always constructed so that any object satisfying them is unique up to a suitable isomorphism.  I usually think of a universal property as _the_ definition of an object, with the construction of the object being merely a proof that there is _some_ object with this property.  A perfect example of this is the tensor product of modules—it is very difficult to compute using its construction (i.e. its "existence theorem"), and so most important theorems are proved instead from this view that it's supposed to represent bilinear maps and so on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A [universal property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) of some object $A$ tells you something about the [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) $\hom(A,-)$ (or $\hom(-,A)$, but this is just dual). For example, $\hom(R[x],S) \cong |S| \times \hom(R,S)$ is the universal property of the polynomial ring (where $|S|$ denotes the underlying set of $S$). Conversely, we may consider the functor which takes a commutative ring $S$ to $|S| \times \hom(R,S)$ and say that it is a [representable functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor), represented by $R[x]$. This can be also interpreted as the statement that $R[x]$ is the free commutative $R$-algebra on one generator, see [free object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) for categorical generalizations. Roughly, representing a functor means to give a universal example of, or to classify, the things which the functor describes. This happens all the time in mathematics. Conversely, whenever you have an object $A$, it is interesting to ask what it classifies, i.e. to look at $\hom(A,-)$ and give a more concise description of it. The [Yoneda Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) tells you that all information of $A$ is already encoded in $\hom(A,-)$.

Also, one of the main insights of category theory is that it is very useful to work with morphisms instead of elements. For example, what the quotient ring $R/I$  does for us is not really that we can compute with cosets, but rather that it is the universal solution to the problem to enlarge $R$ somehow to kill (the elements of) $I$. In other words, $\hom(R/I,S) \cong \{f \in \hom(R,S) : f|_I = 0\}$. This makes things like $(R/I)/(J/I) = R/J$ for $I \subseteq J \subseteq R$ really *trivial*: On the left side, we first kill $I$ and then $J$, which is the same as to kill $J$ directly, which happens on the right hand side. No element calculations are necessary. (On math.stackexchange, I have posted lots of examples for this kind of reasoning.) Quotient rings, quotient vector spaces, quotient spaces etc. are all special cases of [colimits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29).

The universal property of the field of fractions states that $\hom(Q(D),F) \cong \hom(D,F)$, where on the right hand side we mean injective homomorphisms. This says that $Q(-)$ is [left adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functor) to the forgetful functor from fields to integral domains (in each case with injective homomorphisms as morphisms). This is a special case of [localizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_%28algebra%29). Adjunctions are ubiquitous in modern mathematics. They allow us to "approximate" objects of a category by objects of another category.

So far I have only mentioned some patterns of universal properties, but not answered the actual "philosophical" question "**Why** are there so many universal properties in math?" in the title. Well first of all, they are useful, as explained above. Also notice that many objects of interest turn out to be quotients of universal objects. For example, every finitely generated $k$-algebra is a quotient of a polynomial algebra $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. Thus, if we understand this polynomial algebra and its properties, we may gain some information about all finitely generated $k$-algebras. A specific example of this type is Hilbert's Basis Theorem, which implies that finitely generated algebras over fields are noetherian. Perhaps one can say: Universal objects are there because we have invented them in order to study all objects.

Comment: I'd add that 95% of "universal properties" in mathematics can be interpreted as adjoint functors, and the remaining ones are generally Kan extensions.  There is a chapter in Categories for the Working Mathematician called "All Concepts Are Kan Extensions," which gives some idea of how fanatically one can pursue this viewpoint.

Comment: I don't know any category theory yet, so I can't say this answer opened my eyes and made me understand.  But maybe when I do learn category theory, I can come back to this for its insight.  You must have given some good information to receive 5 upvotes.

Comment: @user46944: Sorry for that. Feel free to ask some specific questions here in the comments. Perhaps there is a way to reformulate all this without any "technical" language from category theory.

Answer (score 7):

Any time $X$ satisfies a universal property, it means that the inventor of $X$ chose well (rather than arbitrarily) how to define $X$.

So I guess the literal answer would be "Because people are telling you about good mathematics".

Comment: I don't mean that universality is the _only_ good property an $X$ can have (for example $X$ could be creative, relevant to key questions, or be useful in industrial applications). But universality is _a_ good property to have.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question when I was learning algebra from Grillet‘s Algebra book (GTM 242). At that time, I did understand how I could define concepts (i.e. tensor products, free products and free groups, etc.) with universal property (UP), how maps factor through one another, and how the object defined is the “most general of all”. However, I failed to see how UP is important in other contexts (quotients in topology/groups in particular) even though Grillet stated a lot of theorems in UP, as I felt that it is at most a fancy description with commutative diagrams. And yes, I resonate with you when you said "it is really hard for me to keep track of all of these UPs".

However, now that I've learned more, I found that UP is a very useful tool when you are given a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and you are trying to find a corresponding map from $\tilde{f}: \tilde{X} \rightarrow Y$, where $\tilde{X}$ is some object you've constructed from $X$ with the map $\phi : X \rightarrow \tilde{X}$. As long as $\tilde{X}$ and $f$ is well behaved (i.e. satisfies the hypothesis for UP), you can get a unique $\tilde{f}$ with similar good properties that $f$ possesses. Even better, you get to factor through the map from $X \rightarrow \tilde{X}$.

This idea might sound cliche, since the proofs of UP usually involve constructions of $\tilde{f}$ induced by $f$ in the most obvious way. But in many more advanced subjects, we are defining the $\tilde{X}$'s (some of which seemed very messy) from intuitive spaces like $X$, while we only know about maps from $X \rightarrow Y$. With universal property, you don't need to explicitly state what $\tilde{f}$ is and simply acknowledge its existence and uniqueness, and this is extremely helpful if you are juggling with both spaces and trying to construct such maps a couple of times in one proof. I realized this when I was learing algebraic topology and proving homotopy equivalence of a space with its quotient space (under certain conditions), and it was then when I suddenly realized the power of the universal property in quotient topology.

A final note on "hard to keep track of all UP's": I don't think you need to actually remember the statements of all UP's, because as long as you know how $\tilde{f}$ is constructed, you could easily recall the UP when you need it. It's okay to find it useless when you encounter statements like this for the first time, but keep in mind that UP will be of much greater significance as you learn more mathematics.